# How can I trigger TypeValidationCompleted event from a method in c#?

Tags: c#, events, methods

Usually other event methods take `object sender` and `EventsArgs e` as an argument. For that matter it is easy to call most event methods from different event methods.
But for

```
TypeValidationCompleted(object sender, TypeValidationEventArgs e)
{
    if (!e.IsValidInput)
    {
        
    }
}
```

the second argument is different. I want this method specially for `(e.IsValidInput)`.
Is there a way to call `TypeValidationCompleted(object sender, TypeValidationEventArgs e)`
from a custom method or event method?

Comment: what are you using ? Xamarin?

Comment: C# winforms,maskedtextbox